# Is there a way to see how many users are currently active?

Tags: feature-request

By active, I include viewing stuff.
I know, that there is the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/queries). So are there queries that cover this?

Otherwise I would request this as a feature.

Comment: What do you mean by "currently active"? You mean "right now"? Data explorer is not real time, you know. (It is updated monthly.)

Comment: "Right now" would be a little too short, but what about the last 15 minutes? No, I didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: What might be your justification for this feature?

Comment: @JM It would help people who are not Arturo know if Arturo is online or if they stand a chance to write an answer to something. :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila I thought of a number not a list of people.

Comment: @J.M. Just like the question counter, this gives you a feeling how vivid M.SE is, at this moment.

Comment: @Asaf: at least some of the [John Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) should apply.

Comment: Related posts on [meta.se]: [How many SO users are online?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52720) and [View approximate number of users online](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2631).

Answer (score 1):

I found:

- http://www.webstatschecker.com/stats/domain/math.stackexchange.com
- http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/math.stackexchange.com  (Traffic stats and Audience are quite interesting)

Does anybody know similar pages?

Comment: That doesn't agree with the "audience demographics" I see on Alexa, which reports that, with high confidence, relative to general demographics, MSE users are most over-represented in the categories of 25-35 year-olds, males with graduate degrees, no children, and browsing from work.

Comment: @MathGems You're right. Sorry. I was puzzled.