# Is it possible to see how many users are online?

Tags: support, feature-request, user-interface, statistics, users

1. Is it possible to see how many users (especially experts) are online? or I should find it by checking user by user? It seem to me that nobody respond to my recent posts.
2. Where can I find in my activity profile the list of posts that I follow them?
3. Is it good feature that some users post a comment in other users profile and not under the posts?
   and what about "following the other users"? for example most of time I search for answers of some experts to read and learn from their answers.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to see how many users are currently active?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3618) (on this meta} and [How many SO users are online?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52720) (on [meta.se]).

Comment: You could try joining the CIA. I'm sure they have the tools for finding out exactly how many users are online at any given time, and where they live, and what they've had for breakfast.

Comment: There is no feature allowing anyone to post in another user's profile.

Comment: @Gerry  Also they know what any user's mother's birthday is/was, and the day and year of their first date (and whether they kissed their date, to boot!)

Comment: Sorry for this comment but Do you know that CIA (and perhaps Pentagon) control all user internet activity to be careful that no one reads facts that are contrary to them. For example: once I saw a video on YouTube that was about US tyranny acts, and I sent its URL to my friend in Australia, surprisingly he said that the video is unavailable for him!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

1. There is no dedicated feature to see how many users are online (but see Martin's comment for some ideas); it is also not exactly clear to me what it would mean. Generally, the site is more designed as an asynchronous medium, not for real-time or near real-time interaction.
2. The follow feature is very new. As far as I know such a tab does not yet exist but will be added.    See the announcement [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network) Point 1 at the end.
3. The historical idea of SE is that it is centered on the content not the individual users, historically the idea that *this is not* a social network site was very strong. This is why there is no private messaging or comments on user pages, or anything like this. Over the years SE opened up a bit to the idea of having such features, so maybe it will come to exist. I would not exclude that now that the follow feature exists it is generalized down the road to user profiles, but that is speculation. If you want to follow a user that is still possible via RSS feeds. Look for the bottom of the page for the link to the feed.

Comment: But you're assuming the question is about "how many users are on math.se?", where I see only the question "How many users are on-line?"  :-)

Comment: Thanks for RSS. It is cool.

Comment: Do you know why [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) icon in RSS is not same as MSE icon. It is like 'community wiki' icon. How can I report this?

Comment: @C.F.G I am not quite sure what you mean. Maybe it's a general SE logo.